# Error while getting value from gridview asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView and I am binding the grid dynamically . In this grid I want to make the 2nd cell as editable .I am able to do this , and after I modified the text boxes  I will be clicking on the submit button . Here my issue is in button click event I am not able to get the textbox value.

code

```
<asp:GridView ID="DGridView" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" Width="40%" PageSize="4" ShowHeader="False"  OnRowDataBound="DGridView_RowDataBound" AutoPostBack="True" />                           

protected void DGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TextBox txtseed = new TextBox();
        txtseed.ID = "txtseed";
        txtseed.Text = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "seed"));
        e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(txtseed);
    }

}


protected void butSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < DGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        strDNo = DGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;

        dty = DGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("txtseed").ToString();
    }
}
```

Here in dty is throwing error , can any one help?

Comment: Can you put more details about error.

Comment: its giving object reference error

Comment: You get error  on this line "dty = DGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("txtseed").ToString();"?

Comment: yes. i am getting there it self

Answer (score 0):

Before getting text you need cast your object to TextBox. Don't forget set data source . You can follow this code it's working.

```
 public class Test
    {
        public string Seed { get; set; }
    }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       List<Test> test = new List<Test>();
        test.Add(new Test() {Seed = "ssss"});
        test.Add(new Test() { Seed = "aaaa" });
        DGridView.DataSource = test;
        DGridView.DataBind();
    }



  protected void DGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                TextBox txtseed = new TextBox();
                txtseed.ID = "txtseed";
                txtseed.Text = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "seed"));
                e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(txtseed);
            }

        }

 protected void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < DGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var strDNo = DGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;

            TextBox dty =(TextBox)DGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("txtseed");
            var z = dty.Text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: that too  giving System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     Do we have to make autopost back as true ?